# Regular Expressions - Match inside a Match

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find a way to match something inside a match. I am still reading oreilly's book on regular expressions, but this is something I have to do now:

I need to get all the values from the inputs inside a form. The page contains multiple forms, so normally I would do something similar to this:

```
type="checkbox" value="([^"])"
```

But now I need to target all the checkbox values inside the specific form.
Using preg_match by the way.

p.s. I know I could get the form with preg_match first, and the match inside that result, but I'm wondering how to do this in regex.

Comment: To get the value of `input`s from a `form`, you don't need regex. Is there something else you want to try it for?

Comment: I am using CURL to get the HTML. It is not my form that I am scraping data from :)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("|type=\"checkbox\" value=\"(.*?)\"|");
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using regular expressions to parse HTML.  Look into the [HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).  Using this your code becomes very simple.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.website.com/');

$form = $html->find('#formId')

foreach($form->find('input[type=checkbox]') as $element) {
       //Do what you need to do
}
```

Comment: Okay, now that's useful. Thank you.
Still - the mystery remains, how do I match inside a match ? (I'll be using DOM Parser probably, but I just have to know...)

Comment: Disclaimer: `SimpleHTMLDOM` is _extremely_ slow compared to native `DOM` implementations, see this [excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php/3577662#3577662) on SO to compare alternatives.

Comment: Okay, so then it's going to be easier for me to get the results with Regex after all, is it ?